# Sort list of dictionaries by another list

Tags: python, sorting

Sort list of dictionaries by another list.
I have got list with dictionaries (`IN`) and I want to sort this by another list (`sortValue`).

```
IN = [{
        "id": "a", 
        "val": "Value", 
        "val1": "Value1"
 }, 
 {
        "id": "b", 
        "val": "Value", 
        "val1": "Value1"
 }, 
 {
        "id": "c", 
        "val": "Value", 
        "val1": "Value1"
 }]

sortValue = ['b','c','a']
```

I want the output

```
OUT  = [{
        "id": "b", 
        "val": "Value", 
        "val1": "Value1"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "c", 
        "val": "Value", 
        "val1": "Value1"
    },
    {
        "id": "a", 
        "val": "Value", 
        "val1": "Value1"
    }]
```

How to get something like this?

I have tried:

```
OUT = []
for xx in sortValue:
    for x in IN:
        if x['id'] == xx:
            OUT.append(x)
print OUT
del OUT
```

But value in dict is mixed.
[{'val1': 'Value1', 'id': 'b', 'val': 'Value'}, {'val1': 'Value1', 'id': 'c', 'val': 'Value'}, {'val1': 'Value1', 'id': 'a', 'val': 'Value'}]

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: not the same @bvidal

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can also use the `key` parameter of the `sorted` function. In your case, you want the index of sortValue for the `id` of each item on the list:

```
>>> pprint(sorted(IN,key=lambda x:sortValue.index(x['id'])))
[{'id': 'b', 'val': 'Value', 'val1': 'Value1'},
 {'id': 'c', 'val': 'Value', 'val1': 'Value1'},
 {'id': 'a', 'val': 'Value', 'val1': 'Value1'}]
```

More on sorting with python on its [wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

Answer (score 2):

Build a dictionary that maps IDs to the dictionary with that ID and then go through your `sortValue` list and pick the dictionary for each ID value:

```
id2dict = dict((d['id'], d) for d in IN)
OUT = [id2dict[x] for x in sortValue]
```