# Sorting List based on another list python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I've got a list of objects of the following format:

```
obj = [{"id": 39, "name":"bla"},{"id": 23, "name":"blabla"},{"id": 45, "name":"blabla"},{"id": 12, "name":"blabla"},{"id": 100, "name":"blabla"},...]
```

I also have a list of IDs (`A`) defined as follows:

```
A = [23,39,45,...]
```

I need to sort `obj` such that all the sorting reflects the order of `A` - the first object is the one with key `23`, the second one with key `39` and so on.

I'm thinking of using `zip` for this but not sure exactly how to do so - would I need to zip the two lists together and then sort the zipped list of tuples?

Comment: What should happen if two objects have the same id? What should happen if `A` contains the same number more than once? What should happen if an object has an id that isn't present in `A`? ("I'm completely sure that will never happen" is a legitimate answer to any of these.)

Comment: Another relevant duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624106/sort-list-of-dictionaries-by-another-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First construct a mapping that allows you to look up an item by its id:

```
In [6]: index = {item["id"]: item for item in obj}                                         

In [7]: index                                                                              
Out[7]: 
{39: {'id': 39, 'name': 'bla'},
 23: {'id': 23, 'name': 'blabla'},
 45: {'id': 45, 'name': 'blabla'},
 12: {'id': 12, 'name': 'blabla'},
 100: {'id': 100, 'name': 'blabla'}}
```

then pick them one by one from this mapping:

```
In [8]: [index[id] for id in A]                                                            
Out[8]: 
[{'id': 23, 'name': 'blabla'},
 {'id': 39, 'name': 'bla'},
 {'id': 45, 'name': 'blabla'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `enumerate` `A` and keep track of the indices in a `dict`:

```py
order = {val:i for i, val in enumerate(A)}

# second arg in get could be for any invalid entries
x = sorted(obj, key = lambda x: order.get(x['id'], 99))

# [{'id': 23, 'name': 'blabla'}, {'id': 39, 'name': 'bla'}, {'id': 45, 'name': 'blabla'}, {'id': 12, 'name': 'blabla'}, {'id': 100, 'name': 'blabla'}]
```

Where it will now sort by the position in `A`. However, if you have duplicates in `A`, this will take the *last* index of the element to be the sort order:

```py
# no dupes
{x: i for i, x in enumerate([1,2,3])}
# {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2}

# dupes
{x: i for i, x in enumerate([1,2, 1, 3])}
# {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3}
```

Which would put 1 *after* 2, even though you might want the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Create a dict from obj and then build a list with the order you want

```
    d = {item['id']: item for item in obj} 
    new_list = [d[i] for i in A]
```