# Sort second dictionary based on value sequence of first

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to sort the dictionary based on the value of the first dictionary sequence
Example:
s = {"J":1, "R":2, "E":3, "L":4]
o = {"J":"V140", "E":"21:45", "R":"SUN MON TUE WED THU", "L":"V2730"]

expecting the o dictionary in the key order of s
o = {"J":"V140","R":"SUN MON TUE WED THU", "E":"21:45", "L":"V2730"}

I looked at the example and solution given [Sort list of dictionaries by another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624106/sort-list-of-dictionaries-by-another-list) and tried different ways to modify it as I need something similar to it, but nothing worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the keys of the first dict by their values, and then build a new dict from the second dict with the sorted key order:

```
{k: o[k] for k in sorted(s, key=s.get)}
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcxBC4IwGMbxu5/i4T0pSKgzioG3hIgyKLWDdMtKBptsu4j42dcO0ul3@T/PONmvkmw/aucMCsx0Io40Bt28mbf0Mu/Zmy@B@kfUpnlCa0FZyvMtrTu6NxUu1wp1U@JRHlAfG1o/qM12LKElGPUgbTgLDtWJJ95KQ2CQMErb/hWaGKKfCrP59DZaIud@)